# Display MySql records on web page, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I’m trying to return the last 10 records from my database and display them on a web page. The code I have below only returns one record, does anyone know where I’m going wrong? I’ll tidy it up later with a table, for the moment I just need the last 10 records.

The name of the table is “devel” and the column names are: id, STATION, REASON_CODE, ERROR, WEEK, COMMENT, DOWNTIME, DATE

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(‘xxxx’, ‘xxxx’, 'xxxx', ‘xxxx’)
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM devel ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $record['id']. " " .$record['STATION'] . " " . $record['REASON_CODE'] . " " . $record['ERROR']. " " .$record['WEEK'] . " " .$record['COMMENT'] . " "    .$record['DOWNTIME'] . " " .$record['DATE'];
echo "<br /";
}
```

Comment: You are missing the closing > on the br

Comment: Oh no, I'm so sorry for wasting your time! Thank you

Comment: No worries. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(‘xxxx’, ‘xxxx’, 'xxxx', ‘xxxx’)
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$query = "SELECT * FROM devel ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');
echo "<table><tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>STATION</th>
                 <th>REASON_CODE</th>
                 <th>ERROR</th>
                 <th>WEEK</th>
                 <th>COMMENT</th>
                 <th>DOWNTIME</th>
                 <th>DATE</th>
            </tr>";
while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td>".$record['id']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$record['STATION']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$record['REASON_CODE']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$record['ERROR']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$record['WEEK']."</td>";
 echo "<td> ".$record['COMMENT']."</td>";
 echo "<td> ".$record['DOWNTIME']."</td>";
 echo "<td> ".$record['DATE']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";  
}
 echo "</table>";
```